# Xcode 7: App installation failed: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I have already searched and almost implemented max solution but it's not installing any app even though if I am creating just sample single view app.

> **App installation failed**
>   A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

[image]

Comment: have you checked test target regarding the code signing?

Comment: yes, I did. But it's not working

Comment: There are a lot of possible duplicates. First of all your should look at your bundleId, then go to Code Sign Section and verify the bundleId of provision profiles you use to sign your app. If you logined to your developer account at Xcode - Preferences - Accounts, it can do automatically all the settings for you.

Comment: I have checked those first, even tried other as well still facing same issue.

Comment: @sandy Do you have watch target?

Comment: I had a watch target... the error finally went away once I re-created all my watch targets.

Comment: You _might_ find it useful to read my blogpost @ Medium about [managing singing identity](https://medium.com/@euginedubinin/ios-tips-maintaining-your-signing-identities-and-certificates-c04c482ca493#.jtxicxgj7).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

============== **update** ====================
I fixed this issue today.
First, go to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`.
Make sure Xcode isn't running.
Then, delete all provisioning files (like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.mobileprovision).
Start Xcode.
You will see something like "Fix this issue" in your Target's General tab.
Click it.
Xcode will now load new provisioning profile.
That's it.

----------- OLD Answer -------------

I have same problem now.
I've checked my provisioning profile using https://github.com/chockenberry/Provisioning/releases. 
In my case, my provisioning profile had the wrong UDIDs but right machine count.
I've registered machines, and Apple Developer Center listed right UDIDs for those machines.
However, whenever I downloaded new provisioning profile, it contained wrong UDIDs.
I think Apple's system is outputting wrong provisioning profile.
I called Apple support for this issue today, but Apple only emailed me with their knowledge base links(forums,documents,etc).

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me after upgrading from Xcode 6 to 7.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for even, even when I only saw this message in the Device console of the destination device.

Comment: After restart, go to your account and download everything - then it worked for me! Brilliant!

Comment: This is so great, thank you so much. In my case, I un-click my sigining "automatically manage signing" because I just transfer my app to other company account.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much  :D

Comment: Didn't work for me. It is only one specific account from a customer that raises this issue

Comment: For others ending here with the same problem in Xcode 10+ read the answer below from Matías González

Answer (score 27):

Possibly you are using App Store distribution provisioning profile. Use development or Ad-Hoc provisioning profile.

Answer (score 17):

For Xcode 8 / Swift 3.0
In my case, for my app target and my extension in "General" I check "Automatically manage signing" and it work

[image: Automaticallt manage signing]

Answer (score 11):

I was having this issue because the date/time on my iPhone was not the same as that on my Mac running Xcode ( i changed the date on my iPhone while testing some app).
On my iPhone, i went to `Settings > General > Date & Time > Set Automatically`

This fixed it

Comment: I spent almost 3 hours for this..... the error message Xcode is sending is very misleading.

Comment: Awesome!! I did not even think this is the scenario. I changed my date to future 2 years (for testing purpose). The date exceeds the date of certificate expiry date.

Answer (score 8):

**Make sure you have added device UDID in your provisioning profile.**

- Go to provisioning portal.
- Edit provisioning profile.
- Make sure device is checked.
- Done, download
- Use new Profile

**Another possible reason: Device date is set to later than the expiry of you provisioning profile.This is very weird but, it could happen.**

Comment: In my case it was the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was that the running option in the building scheme was set to Release so it was trying to sign it using the appstore provisional profile not the development or the adhoc one. I had to set it to Debug to fix this!

Comment: This worked. In my case, I'm doing a unit testing and I have my own framework and it's building scheme was indeed set to Release instead of to Debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I could run on Simulator just fine, but trying to install the App on device was throwing this exact error.

I had a test target in addition to the main target. The test target had signing set to a different team and profile. Setting the unit test target to match the main target settings for signing solved my issue.

Didn't notice it had been automatically changed over to a different team, was caused by being added to a new Enterprise team.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it's a perfectly valid answer. (And one that I'm very happy to have found, as I had the exact same problem, so thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I went to the Apple Developer website and added the phone to the Provisioning Profile.
Then I re-downloaded the Provisioning Profile and worked =)

Answer (score 1):

In my case was The build system. I had to change the default build system in  "File > Project / Workspace Settings" and change it to the Legacy Build system.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's because the project I was trying to build is someone else's. The bundle identifier does not match with my team's provisioning profile.

Change bundle identifier to something else help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my certificate is overdue..

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Install the app using Personal provision profile (re-install after going into your phone settings and trusting the profile)
2. Delete the app from ypur phone
3. Switch back to registered developer profile and try again

Answer (score 0):

In my case iOS 14.4, rebooting the iPhone solved it.