# iOS crash when testing on device - debug logs

Tags: ios, iphone, runtime-error

I've begun testing my iOS app on my iPhone. Everything works great for a week or so and then my app starts to crash immediately when I try to open it. When I check the logs for my phone (Window-Devices-Select my iPhone), I see the following log messages.

```
<Notice>: Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.app.App-Name[0x9fed][63]

<Notice>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/64152E86-B292-47E5-A12D-27E5E23CACFF/App-Name.app/App-Name not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

<Error>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 14847: (os/kern) failure (0x5)
May 29 08:46:13 iPhone assertiond[63] <Notice>: Failed to start job 
with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult 
/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 
14847, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to exec}

<Notice>: Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.app.App-
Name[0x9fed][63]

<Notice>: [app.App-Name] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 
0x115657730; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); 
reason: "Failed to start job">

 <Error>: Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11d2702a0; 
 com.app.App-Name; pid: -1> with error: Error 
 Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with 
 bundleID com.app.App-Name" UserInfo={BKSProcessExitReason=0, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x11fa53590 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 
"No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed 
to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult 
/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 
 14847}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed, 
 NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID 
 com.app.App-Name}

 <Notice>: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11d2702a0; com.app.App-Name; pid: -1> exited.

<Notice>: SystemUI unknown identifier: 'com.app.App-Name'

<Notice>: Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11d2702a0; com.app.App-Name; pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x176235aa0; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)>
```

I've googled for these error logs to try and find a solution, but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a paid Apple Developer Membership?

Comment: @AndyIbanez No, I'm not yet. I did not think I had to just yet when I'm still testing on my device? I'm using my personal apple id email for the provisioning.

Comment: There's your problem. Apps signed with Free developer accounts expire after one week, so every week you have to rebuild and resign your app. This issue will go away when you get a paid account, which will allow you to run your non-App Store app for up to a year.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Thank you!

Comment: I got a similar problem but I have a paid account. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951536/xamarin-app-fails-to-start-on-ios-device-after-device-update-to-ios-12 Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation with an app which **Bundle Identifier** has been **moved to another Apple Developer Team**.

After Bundle Identifier was moved, a previous build was containing a provisioning profile which was no longer valid, and I got this error message in logs.

I guess the same happens if you delete the Provisioning Profile or if it is invalidated for whatever reason.