# Xamarin App Fails to Start on IOS device after device update to IOS 12

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have updated IOS on device to 12.0.1 and XCode to version 10. I am able to build the app, deploy to simulator on mac with IOS 12 but when I deploy the app to the device it starts, shows a splash screen and quits. The icon stays but the app will always fall after start.

I tried debuging but it doesn't even get to any of the constructors of Main or App in Native or PCL code.

I don't even know what to try next. All information I have is:

Launch failed. The app 'Tempick.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone (Yuriy)'. Error: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/yzolotarev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Tempick.iOS/896e108cc5f36e1ca3def01022a148c7/bin/iPhone/Debug/Tempick.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone (Yuriy)': Specified cast is not valid.. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.. Please check the logs for more details.

All I could find on the web was restart XCode, restart device, delete app, restart MAC. All of that I tried and it doesn't work.

I am experiencing this for all apps I have. I have a feeling its something to do with the provisioning profile/certificate that doesn't get recognised after the update of the IOS on the divice. Has anyone come across a similar problem?

UPDATE

I was able to trace the device log which reads the following:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
Oct 23 17:37:23 iPhone-Yuriy    Error   52  SpringBoard(AssertionServices)  [com.maddyz.Tempick] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x282837d80; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job">

______

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
Oct 23 17:37:23 iPhone-Yuriy    Error   52  SpringBoard(FrontBoard) Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10a7dda10; com.maddyz.Tempick; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.maddyz.Tempick" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.maddyz.Tempick, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x282836e20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.maddyz.Tempick[0x482d][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.maddyz.Tempick[0x482d][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.maddyz.Tempick[0x482d][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
```

Answer (score 1):

After I have tried numerous approaches I finally found a device log notice that printed this:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
Oct 24 12:50:41 iPhone-Yuriy    Notice  0   kernel(AppleMobileFileIntegrity)    AMFI: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4D4359E4-8947-425E-95B4-82AC4D910449/IOS12Test.iOS.app/IOS12Test.iOS' does not pass CT evaluation, result: 0x80008

Oct 24 12:50:41 iPhone-Yuriy    Notice  0   kernel(AppleMobileFileIntegrity)    AMFI: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4D4359E4-8947-425E-95B4-82AC4D910449/IOS12Test.iOS.app/IOS12Test.iOS': Unrecoverable CT signature issue, bailing out.
```

After googling this a little I came across another stack message
[iOS app won't run on device any more under iOS 12: Unrecoverable CT signature issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440492/ios-app-wont-run-on-device-any-more-under-ios-12-unrecoverable-ct-signature-is)

After changing permissions to Apple Worldwide  Developer Relations Certification Authority to Use System Defaults I was able to start the demo app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning how to work with Xamarin.iOS myself but I ran into the same problem. It has to do with the linker. Open the iOS project properties and under iOS Build change Linker Behavior to Don't Link. This should let you debug on a physical device but the app size will be too big to be able to deploy to the app store.

I don't know if this will apply to you but I also had to downgrade my project's Entity Framework Core packages to 2.0.3. I read elsewhere that other people were having issues with later versions.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows *Xamarin.Forms* isn't available for Debug from the Device it self. Even the "*Xamarin Live Player*" has expired for *iOS*. **You should connect to a *MAC* so you can make the Build for your project.** Even some other Frameworks like *PhoneGap* aren't available for *iOS* anymore.

As always Apple taking all for themselves.

Comment: I am connected and building on a MAC

Comment: @Adrian: Sorry, but your answer is utterly wrong. I am currently debugging my Xamarin.Forms App right on my iPhone.