# swift app crash with error bootstrap BKSProcessErrorDomain

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

While working on a URLSessions when trying to launch on my test device (Iphone 7 Plus IOS 12.1.1) the app doesn't launch or immediately throws error

> Device has denied the launch request.

I've checked the internet for over an hour but all the given solutions won't work. After some digging in the iphone's console i've found the following error messages

> [TEMSIT.Finance] Bootstrap failed with error: NSError: 0x281833690; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job"

and another one

> Bootstrapping failed for FBApplicationProcess: 0x112338cd0; TEMSIT.Finance; pid: -1 with error:
>   Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID TEMSIT.Finance" 
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID TEMSIT.Finance, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x2818334e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:TEMSIT.Finance[0xb0a8][69], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:TEMSIT.Finance[0xb0a8][69], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:TEMSIT.Finance[0xb0a8][69], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}

does anyone can help me fix this of has an answer?

Comment: I encountered this same issue. I am not sure why this happens. In my case, I am using enterprise cert for the app for the signing and production release. I realised that this happens after I haven't opened the app for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my previous direct comment, I suspect it could be related to invalid provisioning profile as I looked over at this post: [iOS crash when testing on device - debug logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248925/ios-crash-when-testing-on-device-debug-logs).

Since the app I was working on is signed and released using enterprise cert, I may need to check with my client's ITS department if they have got an update on their signing cert (I suspect that it could be expired already). I will update this particular answer if I have any lead on this issue.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this issue?