# Changing bundle identifier of signed IPA and resigning with my own cert/provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign, code-signing-entitlements

A third-party company has delivered a signed IPA using their certificates and provisioning profiles.

In order for me to resign the IPA, I need to change the bundle identifier to match my provisioning profile.

I have tried this using Fastlane Sigh (resign.sh), [XReSign](https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign) and a bunch of manual methods listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone) Stack Overflow post about resigning IPAs.

I am resigning the IPA though the Enterprise distribution certificate and installs on the device, however the app crashes on launch with the following error:

```
default 22:49:29.170425 -0500   assertiond  Submitting new job for "ca.mybundleid.here" on behalf of <BKProcess: 0x10130eda0; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 55; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 22:49:29.170487 -0500   assertiond  Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:ca.mybundleid.here[0xe47b][66]
error   22:49:29.172015 -0500   assertiond  Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1475: (os/kern) failure (0x5)
error   22:49:29.172074 -0500   assertiond  Failed to start job with error <NSError: 0x101354c60; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "The process failed to exec"> {
    description = "Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 1475";
    failureReason = "The process failed to exec";
    recoverySuggestion = "Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information";
}
default 22:49:29.172277 -0500   assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:ca.mybundleid.here[0xe47b][66]
error   22:49:29.173927 -0500   SpringBoard [ca.mybundleid.here] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x1c0459590; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job">
error   22:49:29.174034 -0500   SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x113768450; ca.mybundleid.here; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID ca.mybundleid.here" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID ca.mybundleid.here, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c144a290 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 1475}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
```

The specific error message is `Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID ca.mybundleid.here`

After doing a bit of digging, it seems this issue is related to changing the bundle identifier.

I also found this post https://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/code-signing-changes-in-xcode-4/ in which he says the following

> Update: Colin Humber, developer at TestFlight, made me aware of a
>   potential problem with this approach. Apparently, the App ID of the
>   provisioning profile that is used for building the app is hardcoded
>   into the binary during the build process. **If you later resign the app
>   with a provisioning profile that belongs to different App ID, the one
>   in the binary will no longer match the provisioning profile’s App ID
>   since the binary will not be recompiled.** This can cause all sorts of
>   problems with services that rely on the App ID, such as access to the
>   keychain, Push Notifications, or In-App Purchasing.

The post also goes on to say that this can be avoided if wildcards are used in the provisioning profiles, however the bundle identifiers from the original IPA and my provisioning profiles are very different.

Given this, is there any possible way for me to resign the application using my certificate and provisioning profile?

Edit: Is that post regarding the bundle id embedded within the binary still accurate?

Comment: you can use fastlane. very easy, fast. Please visit https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh .  and the command is fastlane sigh resign ./path/app.ipa --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: Felix Krause" -p "my.mobileprovision"

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I have used Fastlane Sigh. The issue is as soon as I change the bundle identifier, I start getting the error `Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID ca.mybundleid.here`

Comment: ok.. please read this links 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248925/ios-crash-when-testing-on-device-debug-logs 2.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Yes, I did see that post. I am on a paid Apple Enterprise Developer Program and the provisioning profile and certificate are valid.