# Getting 'A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found' after transferring app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I just transferred my app account and this is the first time to see the error

```
App installation failed. A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

The app build successfully and runs just fine in the simulators but when I test it in my iPhones ( 2 iPhones) I get this error. My account hasn't expired and I think when it's something with the Keychain because transferring the app removed the keychain but when I check in developer.apple.com everything is active and key is fine.

[image: Dialog with "App installation failed. A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode :7 App installation failed :A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126849/xcode-7-app-installation-failed-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executab)

Comment: Delete all existing provisioning profiles from Mac and download correspondence provisioning profile from your apple developer account and install it in keychain.  And also make sure that the device you are installing the app into is listed in the provisioning profile.

Comment: I tried all of your solutions guys but nothing happened

Comment: @RahulKumar do you mind explaining how to  install provisioning profile in keychain? I kind of didn't get it. Thank you

Comment: Describe what you mean by "transferred my app account".  To a new machine?  Did you export the private key related to the certificate?  Apple doesn't have that, so you would need to move that yourself.  Or, even better would be to switch to automatic code signing if you don't have a valid reason not to.

Comment: @leo0019, After downloading the provisioning profile in Mac, double click on it to install in Keychain so that it will be available to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Project name on XCode, go to Build Setting->Signing->Provisioning Profile

Set the provisioning Profile here and come back to the General Tab, Check if you have the correct Provisioning Profile in Signing Section.

Clean your project and Build it once again.