# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found error Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9

I have an iPhone on which until last evening was able to run an app without issue , my iphone is added to the developer portal and signing is set to auto in Xcode 9, and it was running fine. Since last morning I have started receiving error

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

I can see the device is on developer portal , also I am able to install the app on other phone from Xcode 9 just fine. So clearly this is not developer portal related issue.

I have restarted / fully restarted iPhone a few times and also quite Xcode 9 as well, but doesn't seems to work.

How can this be solved ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006959/9884157

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind this was solved as follows,

Removed the derived data folder and removed the device from Xcode , restarted Xcode, and connected iPhone again , this time it reindexed the device and all worked just fine.

Comment: In my case, disconnecting & reconnecting is all it took to get past the `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.` error.

Comment: ¿Where I found derived data? `Xcode -> Preferences` go to `Locations` tab and you can see it.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed this issue by going to developer.apple.com/account > Certificates, IDs & Profiles > Provisioning Profile > Development, create or download an existing valid provisioning profile and double-click it. It should add the provisioning profile to the device you're using.

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 3):

XCode 9.

If you are sure:

- The provisioning profile was created correctly.
- Added UDID (your iPhone / iPad) to devices category.

If manual import Provision Profile, but cannot build to your phone, then try to **Check** "**Automatically manage signing**" in your project > General > Signing

It work for me.

[image]

Comment: No this is not an issue , I said it was working and signing was set to Auto , check the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a try of this:
1. Open the Keychain Application
2. Choose "Session" in the left panel
3. Try related keywords(your apple id, your team name, etc.) in the upper right search input, you can find all your certifications, some of them may expired, just delete them, and restart Xcode/ reconnect your device.

Answer (score -3):

try to create the ipa by archiving it, and then installed it via itunes

Comment: I want to debug the app thus no use

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126849/xcode-7-app-installation-failed-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executab